# Closing balance Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for closing Balance in below format:

[image]

```sql
    DECLARE @startDate date;
    Declare @maker varchar(50);
    SET @startDate = '2021-05-01';
    SET @maker = 'DCC176';

    ;WITH N1(n1) AS
    (SELECT  0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT n1+1 FROM N1 WHERE n1 < 30)
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) AS Rownum
    ,DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate) as 'Date'
    ,ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(dw,n1,@startDate))-1,0),7) as 'Day'
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) as 'WeekDay' 
    ,@maker as 'User'
    ,isnull((select count(*) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0) as 'Count of Receipts'
    ,isnull((select sum(Transaction_Amount) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0) as 'CUM Debit'
    ,isnull((select SUM(BATCH_AMOUNT) from View_PISBatch P WHERE Generated_By_User = @maker and  Batch_Generation_Date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)  GROUP BY Generated_By_User,Batch_Generation_Date),0)as 'CUM Credit'

    ,sum(isnull((select sum(Transaction_Amount) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0)- 
    isnull((select SUM(BATCH_AMOUNT) from View_PISBatch P WHERE Generated_By_User = @maker and  Batch_Generation_Date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)  GROUP BY Generated_By_User,Batch_Generation_Date),0)
    ) over (partition by @maker order by DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate) ) as 'Balance'

    FROM N1
    where  MONTH(DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) = MONTH(@startDate) 
    and year(DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) = year(@startDate)
    ORDER BY DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)
```

please help me. how to get that as per required format.

Comment: i want in this format.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want the cummulative sum of Debit-Credit, but with a twist: when it's below zero, reset it to zero.

In this case, you can use a query like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate date;
Declare @maker varchar(50);
SET @startDate = '2021-05-01';
SET @maker = 'DCC176';

;WITH N1(n1) AS (
    SELECT  0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT n1+1 FROM N1 WHERE n1 < 30
),
Q AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) AS Rownum
    ,DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate) as 'Date'
    ,ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(dw,n1,@startDate))-1,0),7) as 'Day'
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) as 'WeekDay' 
    ,@maker as 'User'
    ,isnull((select count(*) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0) as 'Count of Receipts'
    ,isnull((select sum(Transaction_Amount) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0) as 'CUM Debit'
    ,isnull((select SUM(BATCH_AMOUNT) from View_PISBatch P WHERE Generated_By_User = @maker and  Batch_Generation_Date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)  GROUP BY Generated_By_User,Batch_Generation_Date),0)as 'CUM Credit'
    ,sum(isnull((select sum(Transaction_Amount) from View_Receipt where maker = @maker AND Receipt_Status = 'C' AND Receipt_or_Payment = 'RECEIPT' and deposit_date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)),0)- 
    isnull((select SUM(BATCH_AMOUNT) from View_PISBatch P WHERE Generated_By_User = @maker and  Batch_Generation_Date = DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)  GROUP BY Generated_By_User,Batch_Generation_Date),0)
    ) over (partition by @maker order by DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate) ) as 'Balance'
    FROM N1
    where  MONTH(DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) = MONTH(@startDate) 
    and year(DATEADD(dd,n1,@startDate)) = year(@startDate)
)
SELECT Rownum, Date, Day, WeekDay, [User], [Count of Receipts], [CUM Debit], [CUM Credit], 
    Balance-SUM(CASE WHEN Balance<0 THEN Balance ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY Date) AS Balance
FROM Q ORDER BY Date
```

In the penultimate line, I am computing the cummulative sum of the negative balances and then I am adjusting the balance with that amount.